# Alfresco Failed FTP issues

Tags: ftp, alfresco, fileserver

I am using  Alfresco 3.4.11 enterprise edition. Last couple of weeks, my Alfresco server shutdown unexceptionably. I seen the error logs below

```
19:54:54,353  DEBUG [org.alfresco.fileserver] [FTP] FTP session request received from 10.118.xx.xx

19:55:00,353  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

at org.alfresco.jlan.ftp.FTPSrvSession.getNextCommand(FTPSrvSession.java:4381)

at org.alfresco.jlan.ftp.FTPSrvSession.run(FTPSrvSession.java:4851)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

19:55:00,353  DEBUG [org.alfresco.fileserver] [FTP] FTP session request received from 10.118.xx.xx.
```

It seems to be FTP issues, but I cant found the solution for this.

Comment: Could you show us more of the log ?

Comment: Try to upgrade alfresco-jlan-embed-x.y.jar, maybe this problem is already solved. You can download this library from https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/alfresco/alfresco-jlan-embed/

Comment: Also, speaking of upgrades, 3.4.11 is unbelievably ancient. I know right now is probably not a good time, but please consider upgrading sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **FTPSrvSession.java:4381**. There you have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since you tried to use the value located at -1 while the valid indexes start from 0.

It smells like you have an array where you try to use `length() - 1` and the array is empty, having 0 elements, therefore the result is -1. Try to wrap things into an `if`, where you check whether the array is not empty. If so, do whatever you have done so far. If not, then in the `else` you need to handle the case when the array is empty.